# Issue with redirection using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect www URLs to non-www https urls for my website. The code I used is below:

```
# Canonical HTTPS/non-WWW
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.rootdomain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://rootdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But the problem I am getting is that my other domains are also redirecting to it. like

> my other domain is www.example.com is redirecting to
>   https://rootdomain.com/example.com

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourweb.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourweb.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: in yourweb.com put the name of your website :)

Comment: de Rosa It worked for me. But what is the fault in my .htaccess code.

Comment: Got error again. the domains which I am using are working properly. But the domains which are not yet used by me are redirecting to the root domain.